# Share only one drive on my network

Tags: server, vnc, networking, media-server

I currently have my Pi available on my home network so I can access the file system via Finder on my Mac (I used some instructions to set this up, might have been these: http://4dc5.com/2012/06/12/setting-up-vnc-on-raspberry-pi-for-mac-access/). I plan to put all of my music onto a USB drive and plug it into my Pi so that I can plug my speakers into my Pi and play from there.

It would be a bonus if I can give my housemate access to my music on the network but without her being able to log into my Pi and see everything. I have mapped the USB drive so that it is accessible at `pi/media`. Is there a way to make just this directory available on the network?

My friend is on a Windows PC if that makes any difference.

Comment: I think the standard method here is probably [Samba](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Samba_(software)).

Comment: @goldilocks Will this be OK to add with the other `tightvncserver` stuff I have going on? Not going to mess up that network stuff?

Comment: If you want an educated guess, no, they shouldn't mess with each other (although you might be able to inadvertently configure them to do so).  I imagine a lot of people use both those things together.  I don't use either of them though so I can't provide an answer, just a hint about a possible answer.  If you dig into [questions about Samba here](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/samba), at [Unix & Linux](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) and [Super User](http://superuser.com/), you should find a lot of stuff.

Answer (score -1):

I go the other way.  My Pi accesses my iMac with NFS.  I use a utility called NFS Manager.

I can also connect to my TimeMachine with CIFS.  I have heard that this way is resource intensive on the Pi, but I don't do it that often.  Here's my entry from /etc/fstab:

//0.0.0.0/Data /media/Data2 cifs user=USERID,pass=PASSWORD,rw,uid=1000,iocharset=utf8,sec=ntlm 0 0

I had NFS server software installed and working on my Pi, but I wasn't mounting any shares and it would complain at boot time.  I removed the software.

A quick google search found this:
http://www.htpcguides.com/configure-nfs-server-and-nfs-client-raspberry-pi/

Good luck.

Comment: Uh, doesn't "going the other way" make this not an answer?  The OP is pretty explicit about saying she has a Pi with attached storage online that she want to access from other computers (plural), including a Mac and a Windows machine.

Comment: I was warming up.  Later on in the message I included a link to help configure a Pi to serve NFS.